# jQuery - Combine <TR>(s) values that are in same Section # with same Group # / remove duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have updated the code, which is currently working up to the Place for each Group #. The existing code determines a matching Section # with Group #, and combines the TR values, adding the Average(s) and dividing by the number of TR(s), and removing any duplicate(s).

I am attempting to determine a Place for each Group # within a Section #. (*example - Section 1: Group #1 - 1st / Group #2 - 3rd / Group #3 - 2nd)

```js
 $(function() {
    alert('View Table Before Grouping');

  sort_array();
    combine_rows();
    compute_average();
  
});

//function sort_array
function sort_array() {
var $table = $('table');
var header = $('table tr:first-child').html();
var l = [];
  
  $table.find('tr').each( function() {
   //get values from td(s) from each row
    var section = $(this).find('.class_section_number').text();
    var group_number = $(this).find('.group_number').text();
    var average = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
    var place = $(this).find('td:eq(3)').text();
   //add to array
   l.push([section, group_number, average, place]); 
    //remove saved row
    $(this).remove();  
   });
   
   l = l.slice(1);  
   //sort the array by section #, then group #
   l.sortBy(0, true, 1, true, 2, false);
   
   $table.prepend(header);
 
   //rebuild table after sort
   $.each(l, function(key, value) {
     $('table').append('<tr><td class="class_section_number">' + value[0] + '</td><td class="group_number">' + value[1] + '</td><td class="grade">' + value[2] + '</td><td>' + value[3] + '</td></tr>');
   });
   
}

//function combine_rows
function combine_rows() {  
  $('table tr').each( function() {
  
   //get current row data 
    var section = $(this).find('.class_section_number').text();
    var group = $(this).find('.group_number').text();
    var average = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();    
    //get next row data
    var next_section = $(this).next('tr').find('.class_section_number').text();
    var next_group = $(this).next('tr').find('.group_number').text();
    var next_average = $(this).next('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();
    //check for section # / group # row match   
     if ((section === next_section) && (group === next_group)) {
        //check for empty average
        if (average === 'No Data') {
           average = 0 + ',' + next_average;
         }
         else {
           average = average + ',' + next_average;
         }
        //set combined average
         $(this).next('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text(average);
         //remove matching row
        $(this).remove();
      }
    
});
}

//function compute_average
function compute_average() {
  $('table tr').each( function() {
     //get average from row
     var average = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
     //split average into array (*if comma separated values)
     average_array = average.split(',');
     var total = 0;
     //total average values from array / divide by count and set     
      for (var i = 0; i < average_array.length; i++) {
          total += (+average_array[i]);          
          $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text((total / average_array.length).toFixed(2));
      }
   });
}

//array sort function
Array.prototype.sortBy = function (propertyName, sortDirection) {
    var sortArguments = arguments;
    this.sort(function (objA, objB) {
        var result = 0;
        for (var argIndex = 0; argIndex < sortArguments.length && result === 0; argIndex += 2) {
            var propertyName = sortArguments[argIndex];
            result = (objA[propertyName] < objB[propertyName]) ? -1 : (objA[propertyName] > objB[propertyName]) ? 1 : 0;
            result *= sortArguments[argIndex + 1] ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return result;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <th>Section #</th>
  <th>Group #</th>
  <th>Averages</th>
  <th>Place</th>
 </tr>
 
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">1</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td class="grade">78.29</td>
  <td>Test Place 1st</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">1</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td class="grade">85.52</td>
  <td>Test Place 1st</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">1</td>
  <td class="group_number">1</td>
  <td class="grade">74.41</td>
  <td>Test Place 2nd</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">1</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td>No Data</td>
  <td>Test Place 3rd</td>
 </tr>
  <tr><td class="class_section_number">2</td>
  <td class="group_number">1</td>
  <td class="grade">78.90</td>
  <td>Test Place 2nd</td>
 </tr>
</tr>
  <tr><td class="class_section_number">1</td>
  <td class="group_number">3</td>
  <td class="grade">91.03</td>
  <td>Test Place 2nd</td>
 </tr>
</tr>
  <tr><td class="class_section_number">2</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td class="grade">81.69</td>
  <td>Test Place 2nd</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">2</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td class="grade">81.13</td>
  <td>Test Place 1st</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="class_section_number">2</td>
  <td class="group_number">2</td>
  <td class="grade">78.13</td>
  <td>Test Place 1st</td>
 </tr>  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please add your attempt and describe how it fails, unless obvious.

Comment: I have added some jQuery code that groups the TR(s) by Section #; however I can't figure out how to get a check for duplicate Group #(s) and just Group those TR(s) with matching Group # in the same Section #.

Comment: Replaced the jQuery coding with a new version that does Group the TR(s) correctly, but still need to combine the same Group # values, and remove the extra TR(s) that are in the same Group.

Comment: Nevermind it's not working correctly

Comment: Updated coding - got it all working up to the Place aspect. Perhaps there is a cleaner way to achieve the same result?